# finding a rational number with a property

Tags: algorithm, rational-numbers

I have to write a program to find a rational number that has a property. I wrote the code to check the property, but now I don't know how to check all rational numbers. I tried with

```
float rat;
for (int i=1 ; i ; ++i) {
  for (int j=1 ; j ; ++j) {
    rat = (float)i/(float)j;
    if goodRat(rat) then return rat;
  }
}
```

but it never ends! And it misses too many. So then I tried this

```
float rat;
while {
  int i = random(1000) + 1;
  int j = random(1000) + 1;
  rat = (float)i/(float)j;
  if goodRat(rat) 
      return rat;
}
```

but this works only sometimes. How can I solve this?

Comment: it stopped being a "rational" number when you converted it to float.  By definition rational means the ratio of two integers.

Comment: You need to tell us what goodRat() does. Checking large numbers of rationals may or may not be necessary. We can't tell if there is a better way if you don't tell us what the objective is.

Comment: not to mention...there exists infinitely many rational numbers between any two, so i think you need to define the constraints of exactly what you want to check more precisely

Comment: @Ollie: all float values are rational numbers. Of course not all rational numbers can be represented as floats, and `(float)i/float(j)` usually isn't exactly equal to the true ratio of `i` and `j`.

Comment: @kaveman: That's irrelevant. They are still countable.

Comment: @PengOne: I don't think it's irrelevant with code like `for (int i=1; i; ++i)` which is supposed to do what? Loop from 1 to infinity? My point was it could be helpful to define the limits of the problem space

Comment: @kaveman, Density doesn't matter if the space is countable. If he wanted to check for every real, then I agree, he's in trouble without narrowing the space down. However, the problem is check rationals is equivalent to the problem of checking integers, which are not dense. I still think he should give more context, but density is not the issue. Infinity is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rational numbers are *countable*, which means that they can be put in one-to-one correspondence with the integers. If you do that, then you'll have your solution.

Instead of giving a one-to-one correspondence, an easier way to walk through the rationals is the following.

Construct an (countably) infinite by (countably) infinite matrix `Q` so that `Q_(i,j) = i/j` where `i` and `j` range from `1` to `infinity`. The matrix looks like this:

```
 1  1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5 . . .
2/1 2/2 2/3 2/4 2/5 . . .
3/1 3/2 3/3 3/4 3/5 . . . 
4/1 4/2 4/3 4/4 4/5 . . .
5/1 5/2 5/3 5/4 5/5 . . .
 .   .   .   .   .
 .   .   .   .   .
 .   .   .   .   .
```

Of course, there are many repeats (the entire diagonal is 1!), but I'm going for simplicity over speed.

What you're trying to do is walk down the columns, which are infinite, so you'll miss lots of numbers. Instead, you should walk along the anti-diagonals, which are finite. That is, take the elements in the following order

```
 1  3  6 10 15  . 
 2  5  9 14  .  .
 4  8 13  .  .  .
 7 12  .  .  .
11  .  .  .
 .  .  .
 .  .
 .
```

So you'll get `1, 2/1, 1/2, 3/1, 2/2, 1/3, 4/1, 3/2, 2/3, 1/4, ...`. Moreover, you know that you will encounter `r/s` at step `(r+s)(r+s-1)/2 + s`, so any given rational number will be encountered in finite time.

One way to code this is to let `i` be the row index (outer `for` loop) and let `j` be the column index (inner `for` loop). Then `i` will range from `1` to `infinity`, but `j` will only range from `1` to `i`.

If your `goodRat` function takes a fair amount of time, then you can speed this up by first testing that `i` and `j` are coprime, and if not skip them.

Comment: I'm just scanning some of your answers and your background in maths/number theory just baffles me! Quote of the day: "_simple test that i and j are coprime_" and you're done. _Sweet_

Answer (score 4):

The [Stern–Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern-Brocot_tree) is one way to generate all rationals systematically without repetition. See others at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals.

Answer (score 0):

First, about your first attempt:

```
float rat;
for (int i=1 ; i ; ++i) {
    // the loop for the first won't be reached
  for (int j=1 ; j ; ++j) {
  // this loop will never end, it will either loop for ever or return something like (floag)1/(float)j
    rat = (float)i/(float)j;
    if goodRat(rat) then return rat;
  }
}
```

My advice is , make your purpose clear, and maybe you can refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern-Brocot_tree